What should we do with the [stream] tag?
I just came across the stream tag, which has 15k questions, and whose excerpt reads:

DO NOT USE FOR THE JAVA STREAM API INTRODUCED IN JAVA 8 (use [java-stream] for those questions!) A stream is a series of data elements which can be accessed in a serial fashion.

and the detailed description is

A stream is a series of data elements (characters, bytes or complex
packets) which can be accessed or made accessible in a serial fashion.
Random access is not possible.
The term stream is also used for streaming media, a method in which
the media can be played while it is being accessed (no full download
required). The ability to stream media is largely dependent on the
container format used. Seeking functionality in streaming media is typically achieved through a different protocol, for example RTSP
or HTTP 1.1's Range function.

Well, you guessed it, many stream questions are about java-stream. Filtering on stream+java gives 2.6k questions, and it’s not immediately obvious which questions are about what:

stream+java-stream gives 183 questions, among which 25 don’t even have java
stream+java+"map" (a pretty common java-stream operation) gives 765 questions, most of which seem, at first glance, to be about java-stream
many questions should maybe be tagged java-io, outputstream, inputstream or a combination of those instead.

It feels like this tag really hurts, because these questions are improperly tagged and thus difficult to find, but I’m not sure whether stream is burninate-worthy.
I’ll try to answer the usual questions anyway:

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
No. Even just for Java, it’s not clear whether it’s about I/O or the Stream API. Moreover the tag wiki clearly describes unrelated uses.

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
Yes. (as long as it’s not about how to watch some video stream)

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
No. This tag should always be combined with the specific streaming API or technology you are trying to use, and then it becomes redundant. It does not help at all to understand what kind of streaming we are talking about.
It’s probably often added because people type something like "java stream" in the tag field.

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
No. It could mean io streams, streaming, java-stream, Bash/Unix stream, CentOS Stream…


In fact, based on that last answer, I wonder if the tag shouldn’t just be renamed io-stream, removing the ambiguity (after cleanup).
What do you think we could do to fix the problem?

I had to resist titling this “Should we redirect the [stream]?” but this is not a burninate request :)

Ambiguity here is very dangerous. One must always exercise extreme caution when crossing streams (Spengler, Et al.).

What problem exactly? That people have OCD about tags? Doing cleanup is just a pointless patch I'm afraid, there will always be the next tag which modern users of the site are slapping onto questions without thinking because they like to #express themselves. IMO... just remove the offending bit from the tag description and let it roam free.

@Gimby shouldn’t we remove the entire tag system then? This tag really hurts because it prevents finding questions properly. For instance I’m watching [tag:java-stream], but a lot of those questions don’t appear there.

Tags should be harder to make, but they'll still be misused by those who can't be bothered to look up what they mean. All of the TLA tags need to be seriously rethought because of this. dsa, for example, I see regularly  and almost never correctly.
